# Accessibility of JavaScript drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, usability

I have implemented my own drop down menu and wanted to clarify the accessibility implication of my solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/tpHcv/5/

The piece of code i am interested in for now is:

```
$('#sub-nav > li ul').each(function(index){

    var $this = $(this),
        index = index + 1;

    $this    
    .clone()
    .appendTo('#main-nav > li:eq(' + index + ')');

});
```

'sub-nav' is hiddden from everyone via CSS to start.  Then it is appended to the relevant 'main-nav' li.  Will this approach prevent people using assistive technology from getting to the sub menu items?

Please don't aks why i have done it this way.  Suffice to say i have no access to the original markup of the project so cannot just append the sub-menu to the markup in the way that i would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For greater accessibility, consider adding keyboard support.  When a link has the focus (via tab or whatever), make sure its subnav is visible.  Similarly, when a subnav link has focus, make sure it is visible.  Some of that you can do with css via `:focus`.

It's unfortunate you don't have access to the markup.  Is there a reason you need to clone the `<ul>`, or is it ok to just move the original element?  Do your dom manipulation with script, but do the show/hide with css via the `:hover` pseudo-class.

This gets you part of the way there: http://jsfiddle.net/tpHcv/9/  You'll still need some JavaScript to manage tabs and focus on the sub-items.

```
#main-nav li > ul
{
    display: none;
}

#main-nav > li a:focus + ul,
#main-nav > li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
}
```

Will your `#main-nav` links go anywhere or are they just for triggering the sub navigation?  If they don't go anywhere, to support browsers with JavaScript disabled, consider hiding `#main-nav` initially with css, and then show it with JavaScript.  This way it isn't displayed unless the links will actually do something.

Comment: Cheers.  Good shout on the adjacent sibling selector. Unfortunately i need IE6 support.  Am using selectivizr but that does not seem to add support for that selector in IE6.

Comment: @Ryan - Bummer, you have my condolences as you work through IE6 support issues.  Good luck!